# Comments in preg regexes using # as delimiter?

Tags: php, preg-replace

With perl like regular expression syntax, you are able to make **inline comments** using the `/x` modifier and the `#` character to annotate comments, but what if I'm using PHP and using # as delimiter for styling reasons, any way to make a comment then?

`preg_replace("/foo # This is a comment\n/x", "bar","foobar")`

works but

`preg_replace("#foo # This is a comment\n#x", "bar","foobar")`

doesnt work, neither does `//`, `/**/` or any common comment sequence I tried.

Comment: if you use # as a delimeter then you have to escape other # that are not being used as delimeters

Comment: It still doesn't work as intended (As a comment annotation), if I escape the # it will become part of the regex, not what is intended. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: dont know what you mean but the pattern is always part of the regex

Comment: Read up on modifiers, the `/x` extended format modifier allows for inline comments using the # character.

Comment: `\#` is all you need. anything with a `\\` is literal (edit - i had to escape the backslash in the backticks in this comment too lol

Comment: But that doesn't work as intended (As a comment). Read my query again, this is specifically about using # comments in EXTENDED FORMAT using the /x modifier and # delimiter.

Comment: you could always just use a different delimiter for that regex

Comment: It seems you cannot use `#` as delimiters if you want to use comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a PHP regex pattern, a delimiter has more "weight" than a pattern part. If you define a delimiter as `#` you cannot use it as a part of another special construct. So, `"#foo # This is a comment\n#x"` and `"#foo (?# This is a comment\n)#x"` won't work as the `#` signals the end of the pattern space inside the regex.

When you escape a `#`, it becomes a literal `#` symbol. The `"#foo \\# This is a comment\n#x"` will match `"foo#Thisisacomment"` as once it is escaped, it is matched as a literal symbol.

So, the best advice is available on the [*"Delimiters"* page at php.net](http://php.net/manual/pl/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

> If the delimiter needs to be matched inside the pattern it must be escaped using a backslash. If the delimiter appears often inside the pattern, it is a good idea to choose another delimiter in order to increase readability.

Comment: I guess this is the best answer there is. I must admit this was more of a curious thought I had. Of course any sane person would just change the delimiter, But I was looking into this for other reasons (pen testing)